# Derivative of $f(x)^T \cdot A(x) \cdot g(x)$ w.r.t. $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

A question regarding the derivative operator:

Assume that $h(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})^T \cdot A(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{g(\mathbf{x})}$, where $h(\mathbf{x}) \in \mathbb{C}, \,\, \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) \in \mathbb{C^n}, \,\, \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}) \in \mathbb{C^m}, \,\, \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^p$ for some integers $n, m, p \ge 1$. Here $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$ with entries given by $a_{ij}(\mathbf{x}) \in \mathbb{C}$.

I know it should be possible to express $\frac{\partial h(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$, but I get stuck in how to express the differential operator over the matrix.
The general idea I want to use is: $$\frac{\partial (a \cdot b \cdot c)}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \frac{\partial (a)}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\cdot b \cdot c + a \cdot \frac{\partial (b)}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \cdot c + a \cdot b \cdot \frac{\partial (c)}{\partial \mathbf{x}};$$
then replace $a=\mathbf{f^T}, b=A, c=\mathbf{g}$.

Can I describe the differential operator over a generic $n\times m$ matrix w.r.t. $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^p$, when all elements in the matrix are functions that depend on $\mathbf{x}$ or am I just hitting a wall here?